# Is there an annotation for @NegativeOrZero / @PositiveOrZero annotation?

Tags: jqwik

According to the jqwik documentation here: https://jqwik.net/docs/current/user-guide.html#integer-constraints it states the integer constraint annotations as:

> @Positive: Numbers larger than 0. For all integral types.

> @Negative: Numbers lower than 0. For all integral types.

> etc.

Are there any convenience annotations for auto generating something like @NegativeOrZero / @PositiveOrZero?

I'm currently using the following code:

```java
    @Provide
    Arbitrary<Integer> negativeOrZero() {
        return Arbitraries.integers().between(Integer.MIN_VALUE, 0);
    }
```

The shorthand annotations would definitely come in handy if available by default.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, jqwik does not come with those annotations by default.
You have a couple of options, though:

1. Use `@IntRange(min = 0)`
2. Create your more or less trivial custom annotation:

   ```java
   @Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @IntRange(min = 0) 
   @interface PositiveOrZero {}
   ```
3. Open a feature request on https://github.com/jlink/jqwik/issues if you think it would be a worthwhile out-of-the-box feature.

Comment: if I were to make a pull request adding these annotations to jqwik are you likely to accept them? I think the situation is common enough that it warrants being in the standard lib..

Comment: If they come with tests and doc, sure.